# Linked list without sentinels

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

Note: I do know that Python libraries provide linked a linked list. This implementation has been done to practice.

I have implemented double Linked List without Sentinels and the code seems to work just fine. There is a Node class that is used within the `DoubleLinkedList` class. There is also a `test.py` to show that the code works

> **Request:**
>   Feel free to criticize and give pointers
>
> **Targeted Time:**
>       Search: \$O(n)\$ at worse
>       Insert and delete: \$O(1)\$
>
> **Methods:**
>
> 1. list_add
> 2. list_delete
> 3. list_search
> 4. get_top

Both class:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.data = value
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None


class DoubleLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None # no need for tail as always the next pointer of last object will remain as none

    def list_add(self, value):
        node = Node(value)   # make new node
        # self.head is either pointing to None or the first object, make the next pointer of the new node point to the same
        node.next = self.head
        # if head is not null, than there is other items in the list
        if self.head is not None:
            # make the prev pointer of the node that head is pointing to point to the new node
            self.head.prev = node
        # make the head point to the new node
        self.head = node
        # make prev pointer of new node, point to head
        node.prev = self.head

    def list_search(self, value):
        # start from the head
        p = self.head
        # do it as long as there is no pointer and value not foun
        while p is not None:
            # make p reference to next node
            if p.data is not None:
                if p.data == value:
                    return p
            if p.next is not None:
                p = p.next
            else:
               return False

    def list_delete(self, value):
        # find the node in the linked list
        p = self.list_search(value)
        # if what back pointer points to is not head
        if p.prev is not None:
            # make the next pointer of the node behind, point to the back of the node ahead
            p.prev.next = p.next
        else:
            # if the back node is the head, make it point to the node after
            self.head = p.next
            # if there is a node after
        if p.next is not None:
            p.next.prev = p.prev  # make the the back pointer of the node ahead point to the front pointer of the node behind

    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            yield node
            node = node.next

    def get_top(self):
        return self.head
```

Test code:

```
from double_linked_list import DoubleLinkedList as linked_list


def main():
    print("----------------------")
    print("Test Add")
    my_list = linked_list()
    my_list.list_add(1)
    my_list.list_add(2)
    my_list.list_add(3)
    my_list.list_add(4)

    for i in my_list:
        print(i.data)

    print("----------------------")
    print("Test Delete")


    my_list.list_delete(3)

    for i in my_list:
        print(i.data)

    print("----------------------")
    print("Test Top get method")
    print(my_list.get_top().data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Result:

```
----------------------
Test Add
4
3
2
1
----------------------
Test Delete
4
2
1
----------------------
Test Top get method
4
```

EDIT: Boundary condition and comparison fix

classes:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.data = value
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None


class DoubleLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None # no need for tail as always the next pointer of last object will remain as none

    def list_add(self, value):
        node = Node(value)   # make new node
        # self.head is either pointing to None or the first object, make the next pointer of the new node point to the same
        node.next = self.head
        # if head is not null, than there is other items in the list
        if self.head is not None:
            # make the prev pointer of the node that head is pointing to point to the new node
            self.head.prev = node
        # make the head point to the new node
        self.head = node
        # make prev pointer of new node, point to head
        node.prev = self.head

    def list_search(self, value):
        # start from the head
        p = self.head
        # do it as long as there is no pointer and value not foun
        while p is not None:
            # make p reference to next node
            if p.next is not None:
                if p.data == value:
                    return p
                p = p.next
            else:
                 return 0

    def list_delete(self, value):
        # find the node in the linked list
        p = self.list_search(value)
        # if what back pointer points to is not head
        if p != 0:
            if p.prev is not None and p != self.head:
                # make the next pointer of the node behind, point to the back of the node ahead
                p.prev.next = p.next
            else:
                # if the back node is the head, make it point to the node after
                self.head = p.next
                # if there is a node after
            if p.next is not None:
                p.next.prev = p.prev  # make the the back pointer of the node ahead point to the front pointer of the node behind
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            yield node
            node = node.next

    def get_top(self):
        return self.head
```

test file:

```
from double_linked_list import DoubleLinkedList as linked_list


def main():
    print("----------------------")
    print("Test Add")
    my_list = linked_list()
    my_list.list_add(1)
    my_list.list_add(2)
    my_list.list_add(3)
    my_list.list_add(4)
    my_list.list_add(-200000)
    my_list.list_add('a')
    my_list.list_add(50000000)
    my_list.list_add(50)

    for i in my_list:
        print(i.data)

    print("----------------------")
    print("Test Delete")


    test_delete = my_list.list_delete(50000000)
    if test_delete:
        print("success")
    else:
        print("fail")

    test_delete = my_list.list_delete(50)
    if test_delete:
        print("success")
    else:
        print("fail")

    test_delete = my_list.list_delete('a')
    if test_delete:
        print("success")
    else:
        print("fail")


    print("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%")

    for i in my_list:
        print(i.data)

    print("----------------------")
    print("Test Top get method")
    print(my_list.get_top().data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Spreadsheet I made with efficiencies: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SHkT-gApL2cl3ensvPmUYYLbaDJrYGpDxrZjOnZRnas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First - and important thing:

```
while p is not None and p.data is not value:
```

You comparison `p.data is not value` is something different from `p.data != value` - and I guest that you wanted the second.

`is` means the same object, while `==` means the same value (of optionally different objects). For small integers - as in your test - Python uses the same predefined object but for e. g. `500` or `-50` it is not true - try in your interpreter

```
500 + 1 is 501
```

and you will obtain `False`.

---

Second, you need not compare to `None` (or to `0`,  or to `''`, etc.) as its boolean value is False. So the same command - in this case the correct one - may be

```
while not p and p.data != value:
```

(and similarly for your other commands).

Comment: for example instead of if self.head is not None  , i should write   if not self.head?

Comment: when i change the while loop to suggested, compilation fails and following error is thrown AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prev'

Comment: IT happens when i change p is not None to not p

Comment: Using `not variable` instead `variable is not None` has one caveat - if the `variable` is able to reach one of the values `False`, numeric zero, empty strings or empty containers (tuples, lists, dictionaries, ...), they are evaluated as `False`, too. (For objects you have to define the `__bool__()` or `__len__()` method in their classes to be interpreted themselves as `False`.)

Comment: Changing your `while` loop to suggested ... - I guess it reveals some mistake in your code.

Comment: yap you were correct, thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

`list_search` (and so does `list_delete`) does not handle the 'not found' case. this went unnoticed as you did not write a test. So the main point is - if you write a library class/function it is mandatory to do good tests. full code coverage and all regular and edge cases you can think of. python provides a [unit test framework](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html), use it.

---

EDIT:
also, from a design point it is strange that `get_top` and `__iter__` are returning nodes instead of values. you should get returned what you insert.

---

EDIT:
in your second version you use 0 as return value for a not successful search. you should use None instead as this is what you use in prev and next attributes. this would also simplify your code.

```
def list_search(self, value):
    # start from the head
    p = self.head
    # do it as long as there is no pointer and value not foun
    while p is not None and p.data != value:
        # make p reference to next node
        p = p.next
    return p
```

in delete you test for None

```
def list_delete(self, value):
    # find the node in the linked list
    p = self.list_search(value)
    # if what back pointer points to is not head
    if p is not None:
    ...
```

Comment: list_search returns None if it is not found, doesn't that cover it?

Comment: says who? a testcase?

Comment: I did see the issue. thank you for pointing it out. as the second part, for what i am doing i do need to pass the node as a whole.

Comment: So you pass test `my_list.list_delete(42)` now? What about `my_list.list_delete(4)`? As for passing nodes outside - i doubt you need to. this is most probably a design problem. where do you need to read `next`attribute outside when you already implemented `__iter__`? and manipulating `next`outside is an absolute no go.

Comment: Than you, I have never used the testing framework. I am looking at the documentation as i am writing this comment and will change the testing side

Answer (score 2):

In your test file you may substitute the part

```
print("----------------------")
print("Test Add")
my_list = linked_list()
my_list.list_add(1)
my_list.list_add(2)
my_list.list_add(3)
my_list.list_add(4)
my_list.list_add(-200000)
my_list.list_add('a')
my_list.list_add(50000000)
my_list.list_add(50)
```

with

```
print(22 * '-')
print("Test Add")
my_list = linked_list()
elements = (1, 2, 3, 4, -200000, 'a', 500000000, 50)
for elem in elements:
    my_list.list_add(elem)
```

and - similarly - the part

```
test_delete = my_list.list_delete(50000000)
if test_delete:
    print("success")
else:
    print("fail")

test_delete = my_list.list_delete(50)
if test_delete:
    print("success")
else:
    print("fail")

test_delete = my_list.list_delete('a')
if test_delete:
    print("success")
else:
    print("fail")
```

with

```
elements = (50000000, 50, 'a')
for elem in elements:
    test_delete = my_list.list_delete(elem)
    if test_delete:
        print("success")
    else:
        print("fail")
```

Still would be better to use the Unit testing instead - e. g. standard Python `unittest` module (see [Unit testing framework](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html)).

Comment: Than you, I have never used the testing framework. I am looking at the documentation as i am writing this comment